# Excel: show day of week does not work (German locale)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, date-time

In on cell I'm showing the full date (like 01.01.2013 > German format) and in another cell I want to show only the day of week. So I followed the instructions from [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/show-dates-as-days-of-the-week-HP010070474.aspx) which refer to the TEXT function. But somehow it never works. If I use "ddd" or "dddd" as format string, I get exactly those letters as return value.

Any idea of to fix that?

Cell A1:

```
31.12.2012
```

Cell A2: (German locale)

```
=TEXT(A1; "ddd")
```

The results are ddd

Comment: Can you paste the exact function/code you're using please.

Comment: I added the functions above

Comment: Can you confirm what the type of Cell A2 is (text/general etc). Also, did you type the code out or copy it from the MS site?

Comment: A1 is date and A2 is of type general. I typed the formular into Excel by myself but following the descriptions on the Microsoft website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use german TAG `t` instead of english DAY `d` if your locale is set to german

```
=TEXT(A1;"ttt")
```

In `Control Panel` go to `Regiona and Language` and change it to German

[image: ok]

then go to your Excel spreadsheet, click any cell with a date in it and select `Format Cells`. Go to `Custom` and if you look at the date in german it doesn't use `dd` `mm` `yyyy` it uses german `Tag Monat Jahr` which oviously is `day month year`

[image: see]

Comment: wow... I mean... really?!?! wow...

Answer (score 3):

Answer is from  [mehow](https://superuser.com/users/222864/mehow) in the comments of this post

`if youre in german locale then you have to use ttt instead of ddd Tag = Day`

---

I think the issue is Excel doesn't know that 31.12.2012 is a date.

If I type in

```
31/12/2012
```

instead of

```
31.12.2012
```

Then it works as expected.

[image]

When using 31.12.2012, if I make the cell type 'date' it doesn't work as you want. Note that when Excel can see it as a date, it right aligns it in the cell. In the following screen, I made the B1 of type date but, it doesn't treat it as such:

[image]

---

You could also try to use

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A1),"dddd")
```

or

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A1);"dddd")
```

(; or , depending on locale)

Comment: My Windows and Excel versions are both US but keyboard and locale is German. So Excel automatically modified 31/12/2012 to 31.12.2012. It knows that it's a date.

Comment: no, if youre in german locale then you have to use `ttt` instead of `ddd` Tag = Day :)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Even though all formulars are in English, I need to use "ttt" as format string. Thanks. By the way: in German locale 31.12.2012 is automatically accepted as a valid date.

Comment: @Matthias, made an update

Answer (score 1):

For German locality I believe you need to replace commas with semi-colon

So the formula would be:

```
=TEXT(A1;"ddd")
```

Comment: I use ; instead , Otherwise Excel does not except the formular anyway. Fixed it above.